# Using two ethernet ports

Tags: networking, nginx, ip, ethernet

I have a machine with two ethernet port, eth0 and eth1.
Currently only eth0 is configured with public static ip. According to the server provider eth1 is attached to the switch and with that I can use internal ips on it and traffic wont be counter towards your bandwidth. 
Settings right now:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
          inet addr:BBBB.BBBB.BBBB.BBBB  Bcast:BBBB.BBBB.BBBB.CCCC  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: *::*:*:*:*/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:526708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:523101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:65971510 (62.9 MiB)  TX bytes:76797538 (73.2 MiB)
          Memory:fb120000-fb13ffff

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr *:*:*:*:*:*
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Memory:fb100000-fb11ffff
```

using ip addr show

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether *:*:*:*:*:* brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet DDDD.DDDD.DDDD.DDDD/29 brd EE.EE.EE.EEE scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe76:c638/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether vv:vv:vv:vv:vv:vv brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What Ip can I assign to eth1?
How can I redirect traffic for my other similar machines through this port and rest of the traffic through eth0.

(I am using nginx as a load balancer)

Comment: Are your 'other machines' on the same local network as your eth1 port is?

Comment: The other two machines are also connected to the same switch.... They also have a similar configuration... Two ports.

Comment: Should I assign an ip manually (what ever I like)  and add ip table rule to forward traffic for particular ip through this port?

Comment: You could assign private IP addresses from the same subnet to all three machines and then you won't need any routing rules. For instance, your machines could be 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3, all with 255.255.255.0 netmask. They will be able to ping/reach each other without any routing rules, given they are on the same switch